# Best way to submit a form each time a section is completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a requirement for a multi-part form which I want to apply some clever submission logic. Here's the idea, the form has 3 steps:

1. Personal Contact Details
2. Quote Details
3. Final Comments

As any good marketer I don't want to lose any data in the event that the user does not complete ALL the steps this (somewhat long) form.
As a result, what I would like to do is **to have the form submit as each step is completed**. So that in the event the user drops off we still capture the details on the completed steps.

Ideally I don't actually want to have the form submit 3 time as, if it was going to a simple email script, we'd get 3 results through for each 'complete' submission.
So I'm trying to find some clever way to store the data and submit it after a certain period of time or something along those lines.

I intend to be building this in HTML & JavaScrip (& if need be in PHP). Can anyone suggest the best route to achieve this (from past experience etc) before I get my feet wet!!!

Thanks for your time & any suggestions

Comment: pagination + cookies/localStorage + review page

Comment: put each step in individual form, submit each one using ajax when it is completed.

Comment: I made a multi-part form once with javascript, where I just hid the sections from view once they were completed, and showed the submit button on the last page.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve this is to have three separate forms, one for each page. Upon the submission of each form make a `post()` request to a PHP page on the server using jQuery, containing the `serialized()` form data. This PHP page then stores the contents of the form in a database for retrieval later.

If the ajax request is successful, show the next page of the form, otherwise display an error telling the user what happened.

Further reading on [.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) and [.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Answer (score 1):

You need server support to store survey's temporary result. When user submits next part, you will simple append new answers to the query. The trick is in detecting abandoned queries, but I think if the survey will not be completed in 24h, you can safely assume that user closed browser and will not append any future data.

You must implement persistance on server, SQL database is the best option for PHP - millions of examples.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly then you are trying to have the behavior of Wizard in the same page, in that case you can use have three forms .

After completion of one section do an ajax call and save the filled in data in some temp database table, finally when user completes the form you can collate the temp table data and persist in your main table.

In case user doesn't complete all the steps then you can clean up your temp table after certain period of time or you can move it in some 'not-complete' table just in case you want to do some BI over the data.

Answer (score 1):

I would serialize the response and store it in a database {id, stage1 data,stage2 data, last_entry_timestamp}.

Assuming that validation is done at each stage before storing the data,

- Stage 1 I would check if an entry exists, and if not create a new entry, and store the serialized stage1 info and set timestamp, else retrieve stage 1 info. (back/forward)
- Stage 2 If not set, I would update the created entry with the serialized stage2 info and set timestamp, otherwise retrieve and than update.
- Stage 3 I would retrieve stage 1 and stage 2 info, and submit. I would then delete that entry.

Finally I would setup a cron job to look at all entries that are over X hours old, submit them, and delete the entry.